# Target and clone specific table cell, Append from top to bottom of second table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, clone

I am in trouble, I've tried to no avail to do something I'm sure is simple to most seasoned developers. 
As you can see, a plus button resides in each table row. 
I want to achieve a two table system where I click the plus button on the table to the left transferring the player in the left table to the right table without deleting the player in the row. The subsequent clicks of any plus button should take the player from the row in which it was clicked and fill in the next open row of the table on the right, starting from top. The click of the plus button should disable this row from being picked again, and the minus button on the right table should remove the player and restore his active status on the left table. When the table is filled up I'm trying to have the ability to add players come back with a "table is full" alert. That seems easy enough, but I've been researching this and this is what I came up with. This feels like a jquery solution to me, but I can't even get started on it. I did the best I could below. For reference think of how fanduel.com does their two table drafting system.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.addplayer').click(function (event) {
$('tr .select').eq(0).clone().appendTo("tr .selected").after();

});
$(".remove-player").click(function (event) {
  $(".selected").remove();
  
  });
  

});
```

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  color:black;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:black;
}
table {
  border: #5a5a5a medium solid;
  width: 300px;
  color:white;
  
}
input {
  cursor: pointer;
}

th {
    color:white; 
      background-color:black;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="left-table">
  <th>Player</th>
  <th>add</th>
  <tr>
    <td class="select">Player1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="+" class="addplayer" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="select">Player2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="+" class="addplayer" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="select">Player3</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="+" class="addplayer" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="select">Player4</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="+" class="addplayer" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="right-table">
  <th>Player</th>
  <th>Remove</th>
  <tr>
    <td class="selected"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="-" class="remove-player" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="selected"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="-" class="remove-player" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You migth want to try this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.right-table tr .selected').addClass('empty');

    $('.addplayer').click(function (event) {
        if($(".right-table tr .empty").length <= 0) {
            alert("Table is full");
            return;
        }

        var txt = $(this).closest("tr").find('.select').text();

        $(".right-table tr .empty").eq(0).text(txt);
        $(".right-table tr .empty").eq(0).attr("data-row",$(this).closest("tr").index());
        $(".right-table tr .empty").eq(0).removeClass('empty');
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });

    $(".remove-player").click(function (event) {
        var index = $(this).closest("tr").find('.selected').attr('data-row');
        $(this).closest("tr").find('.selected').text("");
        $(this).closest("tr").find('.selected').addClass("empty");
        $('.left-table tr').eq(index).find('.addplayer').attr('disabled', false);
    }); 

});
```

To run it you may visit it here: https://fiddle.jshell.net/dgu80ajz/5/

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I meant. Thanks again, I've posted this a few times and never received an answer. I would have spent weeks doing that, I've spent a lot of time combing thru SO too, this isn't on here from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addplayer').click(function (event) {
        var $player_row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $new_row = $player_row.clone();
        $new_row.find('.addplayer').addClass('remove-player').removeClass('addplayer').val('-')
        $new_row.data('row_num', $('.left-table').find('tr').index($player_row));
        $('.right-table').find('tbody').append($new_row);
        $player_row.find('.addplayer').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
    $(".right-table").on('click', '.remove-player', function (event) {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        $('.left-table').find('tr').eq($row.data('row_num')).find('.addplayer').attr('disabled', false)
        $row.remove();
    });
});
```

You are basically cloning the row that the button is contained in and then putting it in your second table with a reference that can be used to delete it.

Notice the event handler for the remove-player class is a delegate event because you want to bind to the .remove-player buttons that do not yet exist in the right table.

https://jsfiddle.net/67g2cb8m/4/

for a working example